# Call method from PresentingViewController after segue pop over

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two view controllers in my project `ViewController` and `SecondViewController` and my `ViewController` has a button which performs a popover segue to `SecondViewController` then in my `SecondViewController` I have a button which I would like to use to a call a method from `ViewController` and I assumed it was possible using `[self presentingViewController]` but that pointer is set to nil so I'm not quite sure how to call a method in the first `ViewController` inside the `SecondViewController` after a popover segue.

This is the code for my `ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)dosegue:(id)sender;
-(void)tobecalledfromseguepopover;
@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

}
-(void)tobecalledfromseguepopover{
    NSLog(@"Called from segue popover");
}

- (IBAction)dosegue:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueforpopup" sender:self];
}
@end
```

`SecondViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)returntocaller:(id)sender;


@end
```

`SecondViewController.m`

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController()

@end
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (IBAction)returntocaller:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        ViewController* caller = (ViewController*)[self presentingViewController];
        if(caller!=nil){
            [caller tobecalledfromseguepopover];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

My UI
[image]
So any ideas on how I can call `tobecalledfromseguepopover` inside `SecondViewController` after the segue? Also is there a way for `SecondViewCOntroller` to know it's being called from a segue popover?

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing is a delegate architecture. Give the popover a `delegate` property and set it to `self` in your `prepareForSegue`. Now the popover knows where to find the first view controller.

This is often combined with a protocol so that the popover knows the name of the method to be called without worrying about the class of the first view controller, but that part isn’t crucial, especially in Objective C.

Comment: Also is there a way for SecondViewCOntroller to know it's being called from a segue popover?